# Line artifact in render?

Tags: rendering

When I render (and in render preview) I get shadow looking line artifacts. I suspected the texture at first but removing the texture in the material it's still there.

Here you can see the artifacts starting in the "Note" and "Volume" text and heading up to the right corner of the mesh.

[image]
[image]
I don't have any bump map, just a simple texture. Changeing the lamp (type and/or angle) doesn't make it better.

Sincerley
LarsErik

PS. Yeah you guessed right, I'm a beginner with Blender. :D

Comment: Have you check your faces for dirty triangles, doubles in 3D and UV editor? Uploading a condensed version of your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ will help others answer your question.

Comment: What you see is the result of non planar geometry, add to that large triangles (or non quad geometry) with a lot of vertices converging in a single pole....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell the exact problem here without a blendfile but it seems like you used ngon's for the mesh (polygons with more then 4 vertices). For hard surface modeling this is usually fine but it can lead to artifacts because cycles converts them to multiple triangles. here this might mess up your topology when many triangles (that are generated because of the holes for the buttons in the mesh). One simple thing you could try is to make sure your plane is completely flat. just select the whole plane and press <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>(or <kbd>X</kbd>- depends on how you rotated it earlyer).+<kbd>0</kbd>
[image]

editmode and what cycles does with it

Comment: It would be my first guess too.

Comment: Ok thank you guys! I have no clue how I should get rid of the ngons after cutting a whole (I used a circle curve and knife project) in a cube mesh. I mean since the whole leaves a lot of edges into two faces in my object. Should I cut wholes in some other way or?

Comment: Just to be clear. I'm aware I'm a total beginner so I'll google about ngons and modeling and stuff. No need for you to answer basics. Must be like 435 tutorials on the topic.

Comment: Figured it out now! Started from scratch, did subdivisions of surfaces before knife projecting the circular stuff. :D